# Is it possible to book return but travel oneway?

Tags: international-travel, one-way

It seems like one-way tickets are always more expensive than buying round-trip. So I am planning to book a return ticket. For example I would like to go on the following itinerary this May. Myself & my friend are planning to travel.

I have a valid visa for Malaysia and I am going to Vizag on May22nd using another
itinerary and will return using below itinerary ( May 28th )

- May 12th - Malaysia --> Vizag  ( wont do journey )
- May 28th - Vizag    --> Malaysia ( will do journey)

My friend did not visit Malaysia yet, but if I booked below itinerary for him, could he do only the one way journey on May 28th ?

- May 12th - Malaysia --> Vizag  ( wont do journey because never visited before )
- May 28th - Vizag    --> Malaysia ( will do journey)

Answer (score 4):

No. If you don't show up for the outbound journey then your whole ticket will be cancelled. Among other reasons it is to stop people doing exactly what you want to do - buy a cheap*er* return ticket and use one leg.